# ( INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... ), how change update condition field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

```
Using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE [KEY] UPDATE;
```

How can I check the update section with a field other than the primary key field?
I want this item to be checked with the title field which is unique.

Comment: Both will be checked.

Comment: ODKU checks for duplicate violation only (which can be produced by both primary and secondary unique index). ODKU does not distinguish what unique constraint causes the violation, it is a handler for the error. If you want to distinguish the constraint which causes duplicate violation then you must use `CASE WHEN column = VALUES(column) ...` in ODKU clause expression.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your explanation. but it dose not work.

Comment: *but it dose not work*  What "it"? Provide CREATE TABLE script, your `insert .. odku` queries and explain where they works incorrectly (from your looking point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i set title field **unique**,  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;` will work with title field for updating.